# CSS Grid 2 columns aren't in the correct position

Tags: css, less

I have the following example [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4sUE/) where i've posted all 12 columns and the required css. the next piece of code i think it's the one that's causing the problems. In the live example you will notice that these two columns at less than 320px screen width will break the container and scrollbar will appear. I've tried fixing this problem but i didn't find a solution so far. Anyone around who can help me out ?

```
<div class="col-mb-2 col-8 col-dt-5"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
<div class="col-mb-2 col-2 col-dt-8"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
```

Update: 
Added a picture to see the portion of the problem
[image: those two columns are move more than the rest]

Comment: i did not understand your exact issue , can u explain properly

Comment: on mobile view the container class breaks because of those two columns col-dt-5 col-dt-8 ( they go a little bit more to the right ) and that causes the entire layout to break. if you resize the live example you will notice that two columns on the right are a little bit off than the rest.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might find a non-class-attribute-based framework like Susy (http://susy.oddbird.net/) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with this class:

```
.testgrid p {
background: #5d68c2;
margin-bottom: 2em;
font-size: 0.75em;
line-height: 1em;
padding: 1em;    /*   <--- this is the problem   */
color: #ffffff;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 800;
font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif
}
```

you need to remove left and right `padding`:

```
.testgrid p {
  background: #5d68c2;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 1em 0px;   /*   updated   */
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}
```

I tried `box-sizing` but not worked.

view this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/B4sUE/1/)

Answer (score 1):

so you need to write media query

```
@media (max-width:312px) {

.col-dt-5, .col-dt-8{padding:0px 2px !important}


}
```

(max-width:312px) means, the width of the scree is 312px or less